# Accessing generic class parameter T from a method Attribute in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, reflection, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to somehow access the type argument `T` of a generic class from a method attribute that is attached to a method in this generic class?

**Example:**

Let's say I have a generic Controller `MyBaseController` handling a certain resource type `T` that is extended by a child controller `MyChildController`.

```c
public class MyChildController : MyBaseController<BlogPost>
{
  // ...
}
```

Now I am using Swagger to document my API, more specifically [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore), hence, I am annotating my action with [ProducesResponseType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesresponsetypeattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to specifiy the return type of the action. This is where it get's complicated because `ProducesResponseType` expects a `Type` argument denoting the class of the value returned by the action.

```c
public abstract class MyBaseController<T> : Controller where T : IResource
{
   [HttpGet, ProducesResponseType(T)] // <-- DOESN'T WORK!
   public async Task<IActionResult> doSomething()
   {
     // ...
   }
 }
```

In the example above I need `T` to somehow resolve to `typeof(BlogPost)`

Any ideas, or is this impossible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Accessing generics in attributes is not available.

Consider an alternative approach

Reference [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

> ASP.NET Core 2.1 introduces the `ActionResult<T>` return type for Web API controller actions. It enables you to return a type deriving from `ActionResult` or return a specific type.

```
public abstract class MyBaseController<T> : Controller where T : IResource {
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<T>> doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

It was create for that very purpose

> `ActionResult<T>` offers the following benefits over the
>   `IActionResult` type:
>
> - The `[ProducesResponseType]` attribute's `Type` property can be
>     excluded.
> - Implicit cast operators support the conversion of both
>     `T` and `ActionResult` to `ActionResult<T>`. `T` converts to
>     `ObjectResult`, which means `return new ObjectResult(T);` is
>     simplified to `return T;`.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! While it is disappointing to hear that there is currently no way to access the generic parameter from attributes, the solution you provided definitely solves my specific problem with denoting the action return type for swagger.